# Combinatorics Theory

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations, relations

How many different functions from [7] to [10] are there?

I know how to answer the question but I was wondering if there were ways to visualize and better understand the question.

Comment: There are $10$ values $F(i)$ might take for each $i\in \{1,\cdots, 7\}$ so...

Comment: The set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is commonly *notated* as $B^A$ and the number of those functions is $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$